# After flattening array using Lodash, how to pick only Objects

Tags: javascript, lodash, reducers

I have flattened this array using **lodash** _.flatten and used a reducer to select the  object type . Any better method for this using lodash.

```
sampleData = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]];
flattenData(sampleData ) {
    return _.flatten(sampleData ).reduce((flattenedArray, indexValue) => {
    typeof (indexValue) === 'object' ? flattenedArray.push(indexValue) : '';
    return flattenedArray;
    }, []);
}
```

After flattening this data, need to pull out the Objects. Any suggestion using lodash?

Output Array :

```
 [{ "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}, { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}, { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by pull out the objects? Using index or just getting a random one?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `_.filter` and `_.isObject` methods to return array of objects only.

With `_.chain` method `const res = _.chain(data).flatten().filter(_.isObject).value()`

```js
const data = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]];
const res = _.filter(_.flatten(data), _.isObject)
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use simple es6 syntex

decrease your bundle size :-)

```js
const sampleData = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]];

const flattenedArray = [].concat(...sampleData).filter(e=>typeof(e)==='object');  
console.log(flattenedArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can iterate each array and add the object in an array accumulator.

```js
let sampleData = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]],
    result = sampleData.reduce((r, a) => {
      a.forEach(o => o === Object(o) && r.push({...o}));
      return r;
    },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) to flatten the items with [`_.last()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#last) as the iteratee:

```js
const data = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]];

const result = _.flatMap(data, _.last);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Or the native js [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (not supported by IE and Edge):

```js
const data = [ ["x", { "name" : "sam", "age": "20"}], ["y", { "name" : "andey", "age" : "26"}] , ["z", { "name" : "jon", "age" : "24"}]];

const result = data.flatMap(([, o]) => o);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```